# Hazelcast Cache metric error with Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are unable to start our Spring Boot application (version 2.1.9.RELEASE) when using Hazelcast (artifact `hazelcast-all` and  version 4.1). I get error

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.cache.HazelcastCacheMeterBinderProvider.getMeterBinder(HazelcastCacheMeterBinderProvider.java)

The following method did not exist: com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.getNativeCache()Lcom/hazelcast/core/IMap;

The method's class, com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache, is available from the following locations: jar:file:<path>/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/4.1/hazelcast-all-4.1.jar!/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCache.class

It was loaded from the following location: file:<path>/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/4.1/hazelcast-all-4.1.jar
```

Action: Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of `com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache` We checked for IMap class - package `com.hazelcast.map.IMap`. Any solution/suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Can you print what is the output when you run mvn dependency:tree | grep hazelcast . This will help narrow down any CP conflicts that we may be seeing with different libs loading different versions of the class .

Comment: we got below result after executing "mvn dependency:tree | grep hazelcast"

Result: com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:jar:4.1:compile

Answer (score 0):

Trying to see if the following compatibility works.
Just looking at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.1.9.RELEASE , the HazelCast version is 3.11.4. Can you change the version of hazelcast from 4.1 to 3.11.4 (on the POM) and try it again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: We use 3.11.4, but when we deploy in kubernates then getting below error :

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tracingFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tracingFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: This is probably not related to this question . This is probably another missing dependency